# SQL 'SET' Issue Out Of Cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've tried to set my variable @MAILBODY outside of a cursor.
Normally I've already using same stracture and not getting any issues.

Problematic Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AksiyonRaporTemp](
    [AksiyonRaporTempID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PersonelID] [int] NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AksiyonRaporTemp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AksiyonRaporTempID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


DECLARE @AksiyonRaporTempID INT
DECLARE @AKSIYONMAILID INT
DECLARE @YONETIMEMAIL NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @AksiyonSorumlusu NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PERSONELIDTEMP INT
DECLARE @RAPORPERSONELIDTEMP INT
DECLARE @MAILBODY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MAILSON NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @MAILICERIK NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @AKSIYONNO INT
DECLARE @AKSIYON NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @AKSIYONID INT
DECLARE @HAFTASAYISI INT = (SELECT DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()))
DECLARE @BASLIK NVARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @TOPLAMACIKAKSIYON INT
DECLARE @ACIKAKSIYON INT
DECLARE @DEVAMEDENAKSIYON INT
DECLARE @TERMINIGECENAKSIYON INT
SET @BASLIK =  CONVERT(nvarchar,@HAFTASAYISI) + '. Hafta Aksiyon Durum Raporu'


/*INSERT INTO AksiyonRaporTemp(PersonelID)
SELECT        PersonelID
FROM            Personel
WHERE        (DepartmanID = 14)*/

INSERT INTO AksiyonRaporTemp(PersonelID)
SELECT        PersonelID
FROM            Personel
WHERE        (PersonelID = 1)

INSERT INTO AksiyonMailYeni(PersonelID)
SELECT DISTINCT   dbo.Aksiyon.PersonelID
FROM            dbo.Aksiyon where (CONVERT(datetime,Termin,104) < CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),104)) AND (Durum = 'Açık' OR Durum = 'Devam Ediyor')




DECLARE CRS_YONETIMBILGI CURSOR FOR
select AksiyonRaporTempID from dbo.AksiyonRaporTemp 

OPEN CRS_YONETIMBILGI

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_YONETIMBILGI INTO @AksiyonRaporTempID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    BEGIN
    SET @PERSONELIDTEMP = (SELECT PersonelID from AksiyonRaporTemp Where AksiyonRaporTempID = @AksiyonRaporTempID)
    SET @YONETIMEMAIL = (select dbo.Kullanici.Eposta from Kullanici 
    Where PersonelID = @PERSONELIDTEMP)

    UPDATE AksiyonRaporTemp SET Email = @YONETIMEMAIL WHERE AksiyonRaporTempID = @AksiyonRaporTempID
    SET @MAILBODY = 'Merhaba,'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)++CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+'Aşağıda aksiyonlar ile ilgili kişi bazlı raporu bulabilirsiniz.'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)


    DECLARE CRS_RAPORPERSONELVERILERI CURSOR FOR
select AksiyonMailID from dbo.AksiyonMailYeni 

    OPEN CRS_RAPORPERSONELVERILERI

        FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_RAPORPERSONELVERILERI INTO @AKSIYONMAILID

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
            BEGIN
            SET @RAPORPERSONELIDTEMP = (SELECT PersonelID from AksiyonMailYeni Where AksiyonMailID = @AKSIYONMAILID)
            SET @AksiyonSorumlusu = (SELECT dbo.Personel.Ad +' '+ dbo.Personel.Soyad as AksiyonSorumlusu from Personel Where PersonelID = @RAPORPERSONELIDTEMP)
            SET @TERMINIGECENAKSIYON = (SELECT COUNT   (AksiyonID)
FROM            dbo.Aksiyon where (CONVERT(datetime,Termin,104) < CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(),104)) AND (Durum = 'Açık' OR Durum = 'Devam Ediyor') AND (PersonelID = @RAPORPERSONELIDTEMP))
            SET @TOPLAMACIKAKSIYON = (SELECT COUNT   (AksiyonID)
FROM            dbo.Aksiyon where (Durum = 'Açık' OR Durum = 'Devam Ediyor') AND (PersonelID = @RAPORPERSONELIDTEMP))
            SET @DEVAMEDENAKSIYON  = (SELECT COUNT   (AksiyonID)
FROM            dbo.Aksiyon where (Durum = 'Devam Ediyor') AND (PersonelID = @RAPORPERSONELIDTEMP))
            SET @ACIKAKSIYON  = (SELECT COUNT   (AksiyonID)
FROM            dbo.Aksiyon where (Durum = 'Açık') AND (PersonelID = @RAPORPERSONELIDTEMP))
            SET @MAILICERIK = @AksiyonSorumlusu +' adlı personelin'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) + CONVERT(nvarchar, @TOPLAMACIKAKSIYON) + ' Adet Toplam "Açık" yada "Devam Eden" Aksiyonu,'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+ CONVERT(nvarchar, @ACIKAKSIYON) + ' Adet Toplam "Açık" Aksiyonu,'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) + CONVERT(nvarchar, @DEVAMEDENAKSIYON) + ' Adet Toplam "Devam Eden" Aksiyonu,'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13) + CONVERT(nvarchar, @TERMINIGECENAKSIYON) + ' Adet Toplam "Termini Geçmiş" Aksiyonu, bulunmaktadır.'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)
            SET @MAILBODY += @MAILICERIK

                            

        FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_RAPORPERSONELVERILERI INTO @AKSIYONMAILID

        END

    CLOSE CRS_RAPORPERSONELVERILERI

    DEALLOCATE CRS_RAPORPERSONELVERILERI


    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_Name ='bilgi.gotec@gmail.com',
    @recipients = @YONETIMEMAIL,
    @body = @MAILBODY,
    @subject = @BASLIK,
    @body_format = 'TEXT';

    SET @MAILICERIK = ''
        FETCH NEXT FROM CRS_YONETIMBILGI INTO @AksiyonRaporTempID
 
    END

CLOSE CRS_YONETIMBILGI

DEALLOCATE CRS_YONETIMBILGI

delete from AksiyonMailYeni
DROP TABLE [dbo].[AksiyonRaporTemp]
```

In order to check if @MAILBODY is working I'm using PRINT @MAILBODY in the inner cursor and I get results but since EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail is out side of the cursor the e-mail that I got is just blank.

I know it just too long to read but I'm totally stuck, so please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build a [MRE] emphasis on **minimal** in the process you will soon find the problem - thats part of the art of debugging - don't try and debug a massive chunk of code. Break it up, get small bits working.

Comment: If I were to guess, probably you have `set concat_null_yields_null on` in your options and `@AksiyonSorumlusu` is getting a `null` result, which causes `@MAILBODY` to get a `null` result. Try wrapping some of the values with [`isnull(..., N'')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) in that area of code to see if it helps.

Comment: AlwaysLearning - Thanks for the feedback, but when I try to use PRINT MAILBODY in the cursor, I get results correctly as @AksiyonSorumlusu. I don't know why MAILBODY is not working out side of the cursor.